# Find files in a path

Tags: linux, unix

I want to search for a specific file type(.jpeg) in a given path very efficient manner.

I am presently having 2 options

1. `ls- R | grep .jpeg`
2. use `'find'`

which one is better one? is there any better approach then this?

Answer (score 6):

I would use `find /somewhere/on/disk -name "*.jpeg"` over `ls`.

There is also the `locate *.jpeg` option which makes use of a database. However, this database is only updated at regular intervals (generally from a `cron` job) so some file might not have been indexed yet at the time you're invoking the `locate` command hence producing a less accurate result. You can force the creation or update of this database by invoking the `updatedb` command.

About `find` vs `ls` performance, `ls` will sort the output which takes time while you don't necessarily need it. Also, `ls` will output a lot of information which needs to be filtered by `grep` afterwards.

Reference:

- [GNU findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/findutils.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning locate, which is awesomely fast when it works.

Comment: Executing `ls -f` will not sort the output making the list command much faster on big directories. I am not saying that it will be faster than `find` though... I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

I've always been a fan of find, there's so much you can do with it:

```
find /starting/path -type f -name "*.jpeg"
```

So if I wanted to start under my home directory:

```
find /home/john -type f -name "*.jpeg"
```

You may want to look for .jpg and .jpeg (3 letter extensions from the DOS days) as files may be named either way:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" \)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want as a result. `ls -R` won't tell you which directory it found the file in, while `find`  will.

Also, ls -R generates more output, which is subsequently filtered, while `find` searches specifically for what you wanted. Without having done measurements, I would guess that `find`  is generally more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`find ./ -name *.jpg -print`

Comment: This won't work. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Manni: Yes I have used this command under slackware Linux without any problems.

Comment: @Manni, are you saying it won't work because the '`*`' should be quoted?  Maybe tommieb75's shell handles that ok.

Comment: Yes, Nathan, that's exactly what I was talking about. What strange kind of shell would handle this ok?

Comment: @Manni: Under Bash it runs no problems! :)

Comment: @Manni: Have you tried it under Bash? Unless you are working with Korn Shell...

Comment: If there's a .jpg file or files in the current directory, the shell will expand *.jpg into the file name(s); if not it will pass *.jpg to find, with the * intact.  I.e. the command as given will work fine if there are no .jpg files in the directory where you're starting the search.  (Also ./ is no different to .)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
      find . -name *.jpg -print {} \;
```

Comment: Why bother with the `-print`?

Comment: @NathanFellman: Why not bother with the `-print`?

Comment: @Tom: It's more to type, and more to remember.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to match the files in .JPG and .JPEG in capital letters. With find, you could add `-name '*.JPG' -name '*.JPEG'`, or you could pipe find to a grep (yes, it's a bit ugly):

```
find . -type f | grep "\.[Jj][Pp][Ee]\?[Gg]$"
```

This will match:

- foo.jpg
- bar.jpeg
- foo.JPG
- bar.JPEG

Comment: Use iname to match case insensitively: "find . -type f -iname *.jpg"  For extra credit, use "man find" to learn how to do OR.

Comment: @Randy: good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious difference with the pipe, both versions can be seen as equal. The implementation ([ls.c](http://www.koders.com/c/fid4DCA9588BF1A4DA19B1A2D5C139BAE53F5348A8F.aspx) vs. [find.c](http://www.koders.com/c/fidEF69956ADA3343C7F63E77E29B9D527861C15AC7.aspx) taken from busybox) looks quite the same when searching for files. You can also shorten the first one:

```
ls -R *.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install "locate" or "slocate"**

Run "updatedb" and "locate \*.jpeg"

updatedb builds a index database for the filenames in your system.

locate will find the file from the database instead of scanning directory by directory.

It is faster that find if you are do searching a lot after each database build.   You might want to setup a cron job to run the updatedb command.

This is kind of like Google Desktop Search, but only for searching filename.

Answer (score 0):

Find is definitely the best tool for this job.
The output of ls -R will be difficult to parse (the file names are interleaved with the directory names).   Besides with ls you will have hard time dealing with names with spaces, whilst find . -name '*.jpeg' -print0 will generate a list separated by null-characters. xargs, grep and others have option to read this kind of input. This means all weird names are preserved.